# jQuery in-page navigation with menu highlighting (optimisation)

Tags: jquery, optimization, scroll, navigation

I'm currently building a jQuery plugin that will highlight certain navigation links based on whether or not the scroll position is inside a matching section.

The way I have it running now works and it's doing everything I want. See the Fiddle [Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adipurdila/egs7hdfk/16/)

The links get properly highlighted when I'm inside the corresponding section. Also, I want to remove the highlight when I'm outside a section.

I'm doing that here:

```
if (scrollPos + settings.offset >= currentSectionTop && scrollPos + settings.offset < currentSectionBottom) {
    // Get the section ID and corresponding nav link.
    var currentSectionID = $currentSection.attr('id'),
        $correspondingNavLink = sectionMap[currentSectionID];

    // If the link isn't active already, make it so.
    if (!$correspondingNavLink.hasClass('active')) {
        $navLinks.removeClass('active');
        $correspondingNavLink.addClass('active');
        console.log('added active class');
    }

    // Because this is the correct section, exit.
        return false;
} else {
    if ($navLinks.hasClass('active')) {
        $navLinks.removeClass('active');
        console.log('removed active class');
    }                            
}
```

The problem comes when I'm scrolling inside the second section and down. In that case, the active class gets continuously added and removed (check the console log) and this is exactly what I'm trying to prevent.

This is not happening when I'm scrolling inside the first section because that's the first one to be checked inside the each loop and because it matches, we exit the loop.

So even if the result is exactly what I want, I still want to make this small optimization by removing that remove-add-remove-add... cycle.

Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Much appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

After following up JeyPack's answer, I got what I needed. To remove the active class when scrolling outside a section, I used a variable that only changes to true when a section is found. After the while loop, if that variable is still false it means we scrolled outside any section so if there's an active class applied we remove it.

Thank you JeyPack for pointing me in the right direction and for the optimisations.

Here's the updated code:

```
function highlightNav() {
    // Get the current scroll position.
    var currentSectionID, $correspondingNavLink, $currentSection, currentSectionTop, currentSectionBottom,
        scrollPos = $w.scrollTop() + settings.offset,
        i = $sections.length,
        found = false;

    // Loop through each section.
    while (--i >= 0) {
        // get current section
        $currentSection = $sections.eq(i);
        currentSectionTop = $currentSection.offset().top;
        currentSectionBottom = $currentSection.offset().top + $currentSection.outerHeight(true);

        // If we scrolled inside the section...
        if (scrollPos >= currentSectionTop && scrollPos < currentSectionBottom) {
            // Get the section ID and corresponding nav link.
            currentSectionID = $currentSection.attr('id');
            $correspondingNavLink = sectionMap[currentSectionID];

            found = true;
            // Because this is the correct section, break.
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found && $navLinks.hasClass('active')) {
        $navLinks.removeClass('active');
    }

    // If the link isn't active already, make it so.
    if ($correspondingNavLink && !$correspondingNavLink.hasClass('active')) {
        $navLinks.removeClass('active');
        $correspondingNavLink.addClass('active');
        window.console.log('added active class', $correspondingNavLink);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside 'highlightNav' function you should better use a while loop e.g. so you can search for $currentSection, get the $correspondingNavLink, break out of the loop and removing/adding 'active' class afterwards once.

```
function highlightNav() {
    // Get the current scroll position.
    var currentSectionID, $currentSection, currentSectionTop, currentSectionBottom,
        $correspondingNavLink = null,
        scrollPos = $w.scrollTop() + settings.offset,
        i = $sections.length;

    // Loop through each section.
    while (--i >= 0) {
        // get current section
        $currentSection = $sections.eq(i);
        currentSectionTop = $currentSection.offset().top;
        currentSectionBottom = $currentSection.offset().top + $currentSection.outerHeight(true);

        // If we scrolled inside the section...
        if (scrollPos >= currentSectionTop && scrollPos < currentSectionBottom) {
            // Get the section ID and corresponding nav link.
            currentSectionID = $currentSection.attr('id');
            $correspondingNavLink = sectionMap[currentSectionID];
            // Because this is the correct section, break.
            state = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If the link isn't active already, make it so.
    if (state === 1) {
        state = 0;
        if (!$correspondingNavLink.hasClass('active')) {
            $navLinks.removeClass('active');
            $correspondingNavLink.addClass('active');
            window.console.log('added active class', $correspondingNavLink);
        }
    } else if (state !== 2) {
        state = 2;
        $navLinks.removeClass('active');
        window.console.log('remove active class');
    }
}
```

I have edit your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cwfqmv50/2/

Comment: This is more elegant indeed, but now the highlight doesn't get removed when scrolling inside a section that shouldn't be tracked... Do you have any way around that?

Comment: @Adi I updated my answer: with the new state var it should now work as requested.